# running arrays through functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm following this lesson guide for JavaScript and trying to do the challenges without looking at the solutions even when stuck. Also, I'm pretty sure my solution is way different than what they were looking for so I was hoping I can get a little help. Here is what I wrote:

```js
let bills = [124, 48, 268];

let tipCalc = function(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i < 50) {
      let tip = i * .2;
      let bill = i * .2 + i;
      console.log('the tip is ' + tip + " the total bill is " + bill)
    } else if (i >= 50 && i <= 200) {
      let tip = i * .15;
      let bill = i * .15 + i;
      console.log('the tip is ' + tip + " the total bill is " + bill)
    } else {
      let tip = i * .1;
      let bill = i * .10 + i;
      console.log('the tip is ' + tip + " the total bill is " + bill)
    }
  }
}

console.log(tipCalc(bills));
```

What I'm trying to do is run an `array(bills)` through a `function(tipCalc)` that returns a tip and a completed `bill(tip and bill)`. There are different tip amounts depending on `bill range(0-50 = .20, 50-200 = .15, >200 = .10)`. I want it set up so the array can have as many values I want and I will get resulting answers for each one.

so thanks for the help! this works but a few questions on how to make it better.

```
let bills = [124, 48, 268];

let tipCalc = function(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if (array[i] < 50) {
    let tip = array[i] * .2;
    let bill = array[i] * .2 + array[i];
    console.log('the tip is ' + tip + " the total bill is " + bill)
  } else if (array[i] >= 50 && array[i] <=200) {
    let tip = array[i] * .15;
    let bill = array[i] * .15 + array[i];
      console.log('the tip is ' + tip + " the total bill is " + bill)
  } else {
    let tip = array[i] * .1;
    let bill = array[i] * .10 + array[i];
      console.log('the tip is ' + tip + " the total bill is " + bill)
  }
  }
}

console.log(tipCalc(bills));
```

for the if statements i have bill and tip declared in each one, is there a better way of doing this? the tip amounts changes so Im not sure if that can be done.

Comment: `i` is an index, not a value of the array. the value is `array[i]`. do you want to get a new array?

Comment: Did you miss a `return`?

Comment: And I would declare `tip` and `bill` variables at top of the function instead of cluttering the function with all those `let` statements. But that is just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code above as mentioned in the comments. Let me just show you one of possible approaches.

Instead of using for-loop (not that it is a wrong approach, but it is prone to off by one errors), you can use some array helper method such as `forEach`.

First, you need to define two new arrays, one for `tips` and one for updated bills - `updatedBills` (if you want to store those values and not just log them). `updatedBills` is there so that you don't mutate the original array (which is usually a bad idea but you can do that if you really want to).

```js
const bills = [124, 48, 268];

const tipCalc = bills => {
    const tips = [];
    const updatedBills = [];

    bills.forEach(bill => {
        if (bill < 50) {
            tips.push(bill * 0.2);
            updatedBills.push(bill + bill * 0.2);
        } else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
            tips.push(bill * 0.15);
            updatedBills.push(bill + bill * 0.15);
        } else {
            tips.push(bill * 0.1);
            updatedBills.push(bill + bill * 0.1);
        }
    });

    return {
        tips,
        updatedBills
    };
};

const { tips, updatedBills } = tipCalc(bills);
console.log(tips);
console.log(updatedBills);
```

Now, you could define the `tips` and `updatedBills` arrays outside of the function and avoid the hassle of returning them from the function and then assigning this result to some new variables (using object destructuring here), but doing it this way makes the function pure (without side effects) which comes really handy once you start writing unit tests.

But if you want to use for-loop instead of `forEach` method, which is fine, then you can simply replace that `forEach` part.

```js
const bills = [124, 48, 268];

const tipCalc = bills => {
    const tips = [];
    const updatedBills = [];


    for (let i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
        if (bills[i] < 50) {
            tips.push(bills[i] * 0.2);
            updatedBills.push(bills[i] + bills[i] * 0.2);
        } else if (bills[i] >= 50 && bills[i] <= 200) {
            tips.push(bills[i] * 0.15);
            updatedBills.push(bills[i] + bills[i] * 0.15);
        } else {
            tips.push(bills[i] * 0.1);
            updatedBills.push(bills[i] + bills[i] * 0.1);
        }
    }

    return {
        tips,
        updatedBills
    };
};

const { tips, updatedBills } = tipCalc(bills);
console.log(tips);
console.log(updatedBills);
```

Comment: Hey man that's awesome thanks for that. That's way different that what I was trying to do and what the actual solution is. Do you have any suggestions on sources that will teach me to code like that? What I'm looking at is definitely not that at least currently, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @marklar That is probably because you are looking at some beginner level tutorial, which is completely fine. Depending on your skill level, I would follow  that (probably much simpler) solution and learn the basics before tackling this kind of stuff which makes heavy use of ES6 features and assumes that you are familiar with JS. As for resources, this doesn't require any dedicated tutorial. Once you will go through basics and then start with ES6, this will reveal to you as a consequence of ES6. And about that purity, you will learn about that from any testing oriented tutorial.